# How can I get the volume of a sound periodically in Python?

Tags: python, audio

I want to open a file in Python (mp3 or wav) and be able to get back a list of the volume of the sound every second or two. For example, if a sound starts off quiet and increments the volume per second, the list should be as [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5..] and so on. The range could be from 1 to 10. How could I go about this? I've tried the wave module but there may be something I'm not understanding right.